# Cut string with variable numbers in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to cut string in a file using the below code:

```
for %%i in (file.txt) do @set num=%%~zi
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (file.txt) DO (
CALL SET P=%%G:~%num%,4%
echo (%P%)
)
```

What I am doing is counting number of characters and cut only last 4 characters in the file having that file always have one line only.

But I only get this output: `~151,4`

what can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to know the length, but need `Delayed Expansion`

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (file.txt) DO (
  set "P=%%G"
  set "p=!p:~,-4!"
  echo !P!
)
EndLocal
```

But if the file has only one line you could simply

```
set /p p=<"file.txt"
set "p=%p:~,-4%"
echo %P%
```

Comment: You need `%p:~,-4%` - note the comma.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou you're right, I misunderstood the OP question. Post edited.

Comment: On second thoughts you may have been right in the first place; the question is ambiguous. The OP should choose: `%p:~-4%` if you are interested in only the last 4 characters, or `%p:~,-4%` if you are interested in all _except_ the last 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a mess.  If all you want is to cut the last four characters, you don't need to capture the size of the file.  You need to enable delayed expansion, `set "line=%%G"`, and `echo !line:0,~-4!` or similar.

If you want to cut the last 4 chars of the final line only, leaving all other lines at full length, then you need to capture the number of lines in the file and use a little different logic.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "file=test.txt"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('find /v /c "" "%file%"') do set /a linecount=%%I

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do (
    if %%I lss %linecount% (
        echo(%%J
    ) else (
        set "line=%%J"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line:~0,-4!
        endlocal
    )
)
```